# Avoir un grain. De quel grain parle-t-on ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques

Dans l'expression « avoir un grain » pour dire être un peu fou. De quel grain parle-t-on et pourquoi ?

Comment: D'un grain de folie tout simplement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Autrefois, le "grain" était une unité de mesure utilisée par les
>   bijoutiers et les pharmaciens. Celle-ci correspondait à une petite
>   quantité. L'expression "avoir un grain" a été attestée par l'Académie
>   en 1740, et signifie qu'une personne est un peu folle.
>   http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/571/avoir-un-grain/

Comment: Ça n'a pas de rapport avec le grain comme unité de mesure, mais avec le sens figuré de *grain* signifiant une petite quantité.

Comment: Il y a pourtant des sources concordantes (et non identiques).  
[Les expression](http://www.les-expressions.com/resultats.php?search=&p=5&tid=36&toid=) (3ème résultat) et un livre scanné par [Google](http://books.google.fr/books?id=OkdDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22avoir+un+grain%22+mesure&source=bl&ots=zaInnOLcB9&sig=7dp_EabJnRXGTFjyNsBdUs-nH5M&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=c2CzT4TtItGt8QORq9W3CQ&ved=0CGsQ6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q=%22avoir%20un%20grain%22%20mesure&f=false)

Comment: Dans ce livre (qui n'est pas n'importe quel livre mais le *Dictionaire de l'Académie française* !) les deux définitions sont juxtaposées sans rapport. Pour ce qui est des sites Internet qui font le rapprochement, je pense que c'est un qui a lancé la mode juste pour faire son intéressant (après tout le monde copie), je ne vois aucune trace fiable qui indiquerait qu'il y ait un rapport entre l'unité de mesure et l'utilisation figurée. Ni l'Académie, ni le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grain), ne font ce rapprochement.

Comment: C'est possible de regarder la 3ème édition de 1740 du dictionnaire de l'Académie sur la [BNF](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l'Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) (liens en bas de page, sur la droite, les tomes 1 et 2, je ne peux pas les télécharger pour rechercher), ça doit être possible de voir. Puisque "L'expression "avoir un grain" a été attestée par l'Académie en 1740" selon les sources (celles en copy/paste).

Comment: l'expression est « grain de folie » et on en trouve de nombreux exemples. Ici 1664: " je me suis senti ému d’un grain de folie poétique et ai rimé le sonnet que voici, une nuit que je ne pouvois dormir". On peut sans doute trouver des références plus anciennes.

https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%80_Monseigneur_le_duc_de_Guise,_sur_la_mort_de_Monseigneur_son_oncle

Answer (score 5):

Un *grain* est (entre autres sens) un phénomène de perturbations avec instabilité des conditions météorologiques qui se traduit par des vents violents variant très rapidement.
Une personne qui *a un grain* est une personne qui a des perturbations psychologiques et dont le comportement ne correspond pas à un comportement « normal ».

On peut aussi penser qu'un grain (au sens physique : une petite particule) bloque les rouages de la raison, le mécanisme de la raison étant coincé, la personne ne se comporte plus normalement, elle est folle.

Comment: La deuxième phrase est dans le même paragraphe que le premier ? Que je sache, le « grain » n'est pas une pathologie au sens médical, ce serait utilisé comme métaphore ? Possible, tout comme la deuxième, qu'elle ait contribué à l'apparition de l'expression. Mais ça reste pour moi des suppositions, tout comme le raccourcissement simple et non imagé d'« un grain de folie ».

Comment: Il semble que la métaphore soit acceptée dans la langue commune :  *Un grain de sable suffit parfois à bloquer le fonctionnement d'un mécanisme ; **par extension**, le terme désigne une petite perturbation bloquant tout un système (organisation humaine, stratégie, pensée unique…)*. [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sable § expressions]. Avoir un grain, devient ainsi : ne pas fonctionner harmonieusement, avoir des fonctionnalité cérébrales bloquées : ce n'est pas la *folie* mais des comportements inachevés, inhabituels, des rapports sociaux bloqués.

Comment: rien à voir avec la choucroute

Answer (score 1):

Y aurait-il un lien avec la "pierre de folie" ? (qui était soit disant retirée du front de malades atteints de maladies psychiatriques par quantité de charlatans et médecins au XVI et XVII)

Comment: ce serait magnifique!